How monitor python metrics for airflow scheduler and worker?
The question is about python metrics!!! Not task or DAG status!
What the problem is:

There is statsd-exporter that expoters all airflow metrics and python ones. But airflow metrics are exported for airflow while python metircs about running statsd-exporter it self.
There are some libraries like airflow-exporter but they export metrics as web page that "turns on" when airflow webserver is running. When I start airflow scheduler or worker with no web - no metrics are exported.

Is there a way to export python metrics (like python_gc_collections, process_cpu_seconds_total, process_resident_memory_bytes etc.) for airflow scheduler and/or worker?
